# Why PROMPT_COMMAND seems to be empty when i acces using system system call in c

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I have defined `PROMPT_COMMAND` in `/etc/profile` as shown below,

```
 PROMPT_COMMAND = date
```

Now when I print `PROMPT_COMMAND` from C code using system system call as shown below it is not displaying anything,

```
system("echo pwd;echo whoami;echo \"P_CMD = $PROMPT_COMMAND\";eval $PROMPT_COMMAND");
```

**Output:**

```
\root

root

P_CMD =
```

Please clarify my following doubt

Why my `PROMPT_COMMAND` is showing empty?

Answer (score 1):

You `PROMPT_COMMAND` has not been exported, try:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND=date
```